# Analog temperature sensor with 100mV per 1 degree Fahrenheit

Tags: voltage, sensor, analog, temperature

My devices only measure analog precision to the nearest 100mV. Most temperature sensors I can find only do 10mV per degree precision. Currently I'm using the [LM34](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm34.pdf).

Is there such a thing as an analog temperature sensor with 100mV per degree precision, or is there something I can stick on the end of the sensor to amplify its voltage x10?

Comment: Before you can get an answer, you need to specify what temperature range you want to measure, and what voltage range you can measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there such a thing as an analog temperature sensor with 100mv per
>   degree precision (...)

I think there are sensors like this on the market, but probably sold as industrial devices (not integrated circuits) and they may be a lot more expensive than LM34 integrated circuit.

> or is there something I can stick on the end of the sensor to amplify its voltage x10?

Sure.

You can use operational amplifier in non-inverting configuration to amplify your voltage by 10. It's very simple to build.

Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Non-inverting_amplifier):

[image]

$$
V_{\text{out}} = \left(1 + \frac{ R_{\text{2}} }{ R_{\text{1}} } \right) V_{\text{in}}\!\
$$

You can use 2k\$\Omega\$ (R1) and 18k\$\Omega\$ (R2) resistors to get gain x10. Use 1% tolerance resistors if your measurement acurracy is important.

LM34 with x10 amplifier connected to output is good idea.

Probably (it depends on voltage range you need) you can use [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) amplifier.

Edited:

It's low cost <s>rail-to-rail</s> amplifier that can work at input and output voltage = 0V, perfect for applications like this. Not all operational amplifiers can do that.

Comment: I hope you understand that, since the original output was a maximum of 3 volts for 300 degrees F, with a x10 amplifier the same 3 volt span will cover 30 degrees F. As in, below freezing.

Comment: I also want to comment that whilst the LM358 that you recommended has an input differential voltage range capability up to the supply rails the output of that puppy does not go all the way to the V+ supply. You would not be able to qualify the low cost LM358 a rail-to-rail output amplifier.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Thanks for pointing my mistake. I thought LM358 is rail-to-rail. Answer edited.